# Uploading text files to Slack channel through webhook URL

Tags: spring-boot, postman, http-post, slack-api

I have a slack channel with an integrated incoming webhook url. I'm able to send json messages and text messaged to this url from postman.

I'm not sure how and is it's possible to send a text file to this channel using the url through postman. I'm testing this out initially through postman and would eventually send it as a Http Post through a spring boot application.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send files using Slack Webhooks.

Ideal way would be to upload the file on a file server and send the URL as part of the message.

Comment: I'm uploading the file to S3 folder, will that act as a file server?

Comment: sure, but the user should have access to the S3 bucket/file.

Comment: [Sharing objects in S3 as presigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) Just found this. Might be helpful to someone